# Get documents in the order same as given array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Consider a scenario, where user wants deals which are sorted by nearest distance from his current location.

I have defined 2 documents, one is `locations` and other is `deals`. 
Deals can have many locations, `locations` have a [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/2dsphere/), and `deals` have array of location ids.

Now, I am getting locations in order of nearest to farthest from a specified point.

```
db.locations.aggregate([ { "$geoNear": { near: { coordinates: [73, 18]}, maxDistance: 1, distanceField : "distance", spherical: true } } ])
```

The real problem I'm facing is to get the `deals` in the order of `locations` that I've retrived.

**Is there a way by which I can get deals based on the order of location ids given ?**

Comment: Your locations are linked inside your deals with their MongoID?

Comment: Yes, deals have `location_ids` as a field, which is of type array.

Comment: Then there is no way. You cannot make a `$geoNear` query on _id's. And since populating is done after your find (because populate is not possible in an aggregation), you cannot make the query work. You probably have a single location used in multiple deals at the same time I suppose?

Comment: Yes, its many-to-many association between deals and locations. But deal_ids aren't stored in location.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. There is no way to populate the deals before you can perform a $geoNear query.

Comment: Ok, so what if I store array of coordinates in deals ? I've looked for an example in documentation which uses MultiPoint type, but there isn't any.